# broadcast listener called twice in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a login controller where I am trying to signup/login:

```
app.controller('signupController', function($scope, $sessionStorage, $state, authService){

    $scope.$storage = $sessionStorage;

    $scope.socialAuthentication = function(e){
        authService.login(e);
    };

    $scope.logout = function(e){
        authService.logout();
    };

    $scope.$on('authenticate', function(event, data){
        console.log('user ', data); // prints twice here
        if(data != null && data.access_token != ""){
            $scope.$storage.isLoggedIn = true;
        } else {
            $scope.$storage.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
        $state.go('home');
    });
});
```

Auth Service:

```
app.service('authService', function($rootScope, $http){

    this.login = function(e){
        var social = e.currentTarget.dataset.social;
        popupTools.popup('/auth/'+social+'/', "Authentication", {}, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                return false;
            } else {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('authenticate', user);
            }
        });
    };

    this.logout = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('authenticate', null);
    };
});
```

The problem is `$scope.$on` is called twice printing the log messages twice. Why is that so, I am not able to understand.

Comment: is the controller (signupController) used twice somewhere? if so since there are two controllers there will be two seperate $scope.$on function's getting triggered by $broadcast

Comment: @NarenMurali You mean ng-controller attribute?

Comment: have you defined the `ng-controller="signupController"` attribute twice somewhere or defined it also in a route, also on the $scope.$on if you do a console.log("dummy") you can check from which line its coming. open the console. and the line number and file from where it was printed will come

Comment: @NarenMurali Yes I have used `ng-controller="signupController"` in two different html files(views)

Comment: @NarenMurali In header html file and signup.html file because I needed it in both places.

Comment: I mean that; that's why you are getting the console.log() output twice, I dont think its an issue if it happens twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151751/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-kittu).